# How To Make Trigger IF ELSE with query in php

Tags: php

I want to make a trigger `ini` PHP using IF/ELSE. But when I Try it, it didn't work could you solve this?

Below is the code

```
IF type='Non-Celup' THEN
BEGIN
UPDATE stock_benang SET
cones=cones-NEW.cones,kg=kg-NEW.kg WHERE id_stock = NEW.id_stock;
END;
ELSEIF type='Celup' THEN
BEGIN
UPDATE stock_benang SET
cones=cones+NEW.cones,kg=kg+NEW.kg WHERE id_stock = NEW.id_stock;
END;
```

Comment: This does not look like PHP at all. Is this SQL?

Comment: Looks like a straightforward copy of the SQL trigger so has not been PHP'ed at all.